# Simple Webradiostream in OSX

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I wanna build my first macOS-App. The aim is, that I can select a radiostream and play this. But it doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```
import Cocoa
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

class ViewController: NSViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var RadioList: NSPopUpButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let RadioListArray = ["Unser Radio", "Antenne"]

    RadioList.removeAllItems()
    RadioList.addItems(withTitles: RadioListArray)
    RadioList.selectItem(at: 0)
}

override var representedObject: Any? {
    didSet {
    // Update the view, if already loaded.
    }
}

@IBAction func PlayStopButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    var url = String()

    switch RadioList.indexOfSelectedItem {
    case 0:
        url = "http://rs4.stream24.net:80/unser-radio.mp3"
    case 1:
        url = "http://mp3channels.webradio.antenne.de/antenne"
    default:
        print("nothing")
    }
    Stream(url: url)
}

func Stream(url: String)
{
    print(url)

    let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: url)!)
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.view.layer?.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    player.play()
}
}
```

When I copy the url's direct to the browser, than the streaming start well. When I insert a Video, then the video starts in the application.

Is der something special for audiostreaming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is because apple is not allowing you to load any `http` contents by default. if you looks closely on debug console you might have got this below error

> App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://)
>   resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be
>   configured via your app's Info.plist file.

To solve it just add below to your `info.plist` file

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

Detailed info can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http) SO answer